# How transmit data using bluetooth in another activity?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm new to java programming and I have a problem. Im working at a controller for arduino car using bluetooth. The car has 3 runnig modes: *Test*,*Auto* and *Manual*. I made a MainActivity that has a layout with 3 buttons for every mode and a button *Connect* for bluetooth connection. In another activity *SecondActivity* that has another layout with buttons for controling the direction and speed of the car,but surprisingly *mBluetooth.write* is not working.

This is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton test, manual,connect;
Button back;

private BluetoothAdapter mbluetoothAdapter;
protected AlertDialog.Builder builder;
ConnectThread mBluetooth = new ConnectThread();
String mBluetoothName = "";
String mBluetoothAdress = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Context context = this;
    //final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    //final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_main);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mbluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    connect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    test = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.test);
    manual = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.manual);


    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class );
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    manual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class );
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mbluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivity(enableBtIntent);
            } else {
                if (!mBluetooth.mBluetoothAddress.equals("")) {//if another connection is already exits then close it first
                    stopAllActivities();
                } else {
                    try {
                        Intent serverIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(serverIntent, Helper.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        showToast(getString(R.string.errorOccured) + ": " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Helper.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                mBluetoothName = data.getExtras().getString(Helper.EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_NAME);
                mBluetoothAdress = data.getExtras().getString(Helper.EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS);

                // setBluetoothInfo();
                showToast(R.string.connectedDevice + mBluetoothName);

                if (!mBluetoothAdress.equals("")) {
                    if (!mBluetooth.connect(mBluetoothAdress)){


                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void stopAllActivities() {
    mBluetooth.write("S"); //send Stop Signal before it closes the connection

    mBluetooth.mBluetoothAddress = ""; // reset address
    mBluetooth.close();//close Connection

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mbluetoothAdapter != null) {
        if (mbluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mbluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    }
    super.onPause();
}}
```

And this is the SecondActivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final Context context = this;
Button back;
ImageButton btnup, btndown, btnright, btnleft;
ConnectThread mBluetooth = new ConnectThread();//??????

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    btnup = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnup);
    btndown = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btndown);
    btnleft = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnleft);
    btnright = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnright);
    final TextView direction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_direction);
    final TextView steering = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.steering_direction);
    final Chronometer chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    btndown.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mBluetooth.write("2");
                direction.setText(R.string.Backwards);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mBluetooth.write("x");
                direction.setText(R.string.blank);
            }


            return false;

        }
    });
    btnup.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mBluetooth.write("8");
                direction.setText(R.string.Forward);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mBluetooth.write("z");
                direction.setText(R.string.blank);
            }


            return false;

        }
    });

    btnright.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mBluetooth.write("6");
                steering.setText(R.string.Right);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mBluetooth.write("c");
                steering.setText(R.string.none);
            }


            return false;

        }
    });
    btnleft.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mBluetooth.write("4");
                steering.setText(R.string.Left);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mBluetooth.write("v");
                steering.setText(R.string.none);
            }


            return false;

        }
    });


}}
```

I tested the code for bluetooth connection and buttons in one activity and worked fine

Answer (score 0):

This may be a workout. 
Make the `ConnectThread` instance `mBluetooth` static in MainActivity. Now this will act as class field and will retain its instance till entire lifecycle of app.

Here is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton test, manual,connect;
Button back;

private BluetoothAdapter mbluetoothAdapter;
protected AlertDialog.Builder builder;
//Static instance declaration
public static ConnectThread mBluetooth;
String mBluetoothName = "";
String mBluetoothAdress = "";

//Static block to initialise static instance
static{
    mBluetooth=new ConnectThread();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Context context = this;
    //final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    //final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_main);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mbluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    connect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    test = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.test);
    manual = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.manual);


    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class );
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    manual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class );
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mbluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivity(enableBtIntent);
            } else {
                if (!mBluetooth.mBluetoothAddress.equals("")) {//if another connection is already exits then close it first
                    stopAllActivities();
                } else {
                    try {
                        Intent serverIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(serverIntent, Helper.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        showToast(getString(R.string.errorOccured) + ": " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Helper.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                mBluetoothName = data.getExtras().getString(Helper.EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_NAME);
                mBluetoothAdress = data.getExtras().getString(Helper.EXTRA_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS);

                // setBluetoothInfo();
                showToast(R.string.connectedDevice + mBluetoothName);

                if (!mBluetoothAdress.equals("")) {
                    if (!mBluetooth.connect(mBluetoothAdress)){


                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void stopAllActivities() {
    mBluetooth.write("S"); //send Stop Signal before it closes the connection

    mBluetooth.mBluetoothAddress = ""; // reset address
    mBluetooth.close();//close Connection

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mbluetoothAdapter != null) {
        if (mbluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mbluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    }
    super.onPause();
}}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final Context context = this;
Button back;
ImageButton btnup, btndown, btnright, btnleft;
//Declare a static reference from MainActivity class
ConnectThread mBluetooth = MainActivity.mBluetooth;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    btnup = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnup);
    btndown = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btndown);
    btnleft = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnleft);
    btnright = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnright);
    final TextView direction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_direction);
    final TextView steering = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.steering_direction);
    final Chronometer chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    btndown.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mBluetooth.write("2");
                direction.setText(R.string.Backwards);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mBluetooth.write("x");
                direction.setText(R.string.blank);
            }


            return false;

        }
    });
    btnup.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mBluetooth.write("8");
                direction.setText(R.string.Forward);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mBluetooth.write("z");
                direction.setText(R.string.blank);
            }


            return false;

        }
    });

    btnright.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mBluetooth.write("6");
                steering.setText(R.string.Right);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mBluetooth.write("c");
                steering.setText(R.string.none);
            }


            return false;

        }
    });
    btnleft.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mBluetooth.write("4");
                steering.setText(R.string.Left);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mBluetooth.write("v");
                steering.setText(R.string.none);
            }


            return false;

        }
    });


}}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code I found in the second activity:

```
ConnectThread mBluetooth = new ConnectThread(); //??????
```

What means you are creating another object that is different to the created in the MainAvtivity, so this new object have not connected. This explain why if you use the same object in the same MainActivity the method write works.

I suggest you make this object static and use it in the secondActivity. So remove the

```
ConnectThread mBluetooth = new ConnectThread(); //??????
```

make static mBluetooth object in MainActivity

```
Static ConnectThread mBluetooth = new ConnectThread();
```

and we you need to write something in SecondActivity use

```
MainAcivity.mBluetooth.write(data);
```

It is not recommended at all make object static but if it's no a big app is a good workaround.

Hope this help you!